# FS write file is breaking my json, how to correctly update just one key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I have a simple json object like so.

```
 {
      "gymData": {
        "previousWorkouts": [
        ],
        "exercises": [
        ]
      }
    }
```

both of the arrays above, are full of objects. I have 2 end points `/workouts` and `/exercises`.

my backend is just a simple express server with custom end points. when I add a new workout in the frontend and click submit, the `/workouts` endpoint behaves correctly.

however, I'm getting some issue when it's not updating the json correctly and resulting in a json error.

this is my node endpoint code

```
app.post("/exercises", function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('db.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
     if (err) throw err;
     let databaseData = JSON.parse(data);
     const workoutExercises = req.body.workoutExercises.workouts
     workoutExercises.forEach(exercise => {
       const filteredExerciseDatabase = databaseData.gymData.exercises.filter(ex => ex.name === exercise.name)
       filteredExerciseDatabase[0].previousWeights.push({date: req.body.date, weight: exercise.weight})
     })
     const updatedData = JSON.stringify(databaseData)
     console.log(updatedData)
     fs.writeFile('db.json', updatedData, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
         res.status(200).send("Basket was updated");
     });
  });
})
```

instead of writing the whole file again. I was wondering if I can just update the specific object key that I need too?

also, for reference, the error seems to be appending extra stuff onto the json object, so it's breaking. but in this line: `console.log(updatedData)` when I copy that logged data into a json validator, it is valid. so I'm confused as to why it's not writing the correct thing :/

Comment: Sounds like a concurrency issue to me, where multiple requests to `/exercises` are getting in each others way.

Comment: *"instead of writing the whole file again. I was wondering if I can just update the specific object key that I need too?"* No. If you want to do that, JSON isn't the right thing to use.

Comment: If you don't want to use full featured db-engine, consider file-based db `sqlite`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what would be the correct thing to use then? would I need to use a database like firebase? and have my endpoints be the middle ground between the two?

Comment: Probably a DB of some kind, yes, or some kind of structure you can append to and then (perhaps) periodically condense. As robertklep said, though, the problem here is probably concurrency, since the code you've shown should be fine if it never runs twice at the same time and nothing else ever writes to that file.